# MVC ActionLink html attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, actionlink

I want to use ActionLink instead of plain html to popup my modal window but its working fine with plain html tag but not with MVC actionlink please have a look below.

from: (working)

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

to: (error)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { id = @item.Id }, new { @data-toggle="modal", @data-target="#myModal" })
```

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: You need to use the underscore character - `new { data_toggle="modal", data_target="#myModal" }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the underscore character instead or the hyphen character in the attribute name (the html helper will output the html correctly). Note also the `@` character is not required (its only necessary when using a reserved word, e.g. `class` or `readonly`)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", null, new { id = @item.Id }, new { data_toggle="modal", data_target="#myModal" })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Html.ActionLink("TextLink", "ActionName", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class="btn btn-primary", data_toggle="modal", data_target="#exampleModal" })
```